# Cnvert nginx try file_files to apache rule

Tags: apache, nginx

Hiiii,
I would like to convert this to apache

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php
}
```

How can i do ?
Thanks you

Comment: What PHP framework make you need for this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. I copy it from Laravel which is really common PHP framework

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I gonna try it thanks you